# How Difficult / Expensive is it to Swap An Automatic Transmission?

Tags: automatic-transmission

Let's say you are thinking of getting a car cheap due to it having a spotty automatic transmission.  How difficult / expensive would it typically be to get a low mileage second hand transmission from a wreak and have it swapped it in?

For example, a 99 Mazda 626?

Comment: You need to be more specific with regards to which vehicle you're talking about. The ease/expense will depend on the vehicle in question, so the answers to the question in its present form are likely to be subjective

Answer (score 3):

If you are talking about just replacing with a remanufactured or brand new tranny, that in itself is not too difficult, provided you have proper jacking equipment.  Preferred would be a [special tranny jack](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00028FB6S) but I have heard of people using a regular trolley jack with a [tranny adapter](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00080QGYG).  In either case, the critical component is a 4-pointed fork on which you rest the heavy gearbox, which a regular jack doesn't have.

Once you have taken the old gearbox out, you can either take it to a tranny shop to have them rebuild it or try to rebuild it yourself, which of course adds significant complexity.  I have heard that shops charge a lot of money to just take it down and reinstall it so you may want to perform just that part and have a professional do the tedious work for you.

Comment: I was thinking more along the lines of buying a low mileage used tranny from a wreaking yard and having someone put it in for me.

Comment: that involves only the easier scenario described in my answer

Comment: @amphibient being a 626 which is a FWD car, it will probably involve dropping the subframe as well to remove it, so he'll more than likely want an engine hoist to support the engine while doing that.